# Does a gulp task have to return anything?

Tags: javascript, build-process, gulp

In online examples showing usage of gulp, some tasks return the stream and others don't.

For example, without a return:

```
gulp.task('tsc', function()
{
    gulp.src('**/*.ts')
        // ...
});
```

And the same code, with a return:

```
gulp.task('tsc', function()
{
    return gulp.src('**/*.ts')
        // ...
});
```

Is it necessary to return the stream?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you do not return a stream, then the asynchronous result of each task will not be awaited by its caller, nor any dependent tasks.

For example, when not returning streams:

```
$ gulp scripts
[21:25:05] Using gulpfile ~/my-project/gulpfile.js
[21:25:05] Starting 'tsc'...
[21:25:05] Finished 'tsc' after 13 ms
[21:25:05] Starting 'scripts'...
[21:25:05] Finished 'scripts' after 10 ms
[21:25:05] Compiling TypeScript files using tsc version 1.0.1.0
```

Note here that the `scripts` task depends upon the `tsc` task. It reports that `tsc` completes in 13 milliseconds, which is definitely too fast to be reasonably believed. Then the `scripts` task appears to start and complete, again in a very small period of time. Finally, the actual operation performed by `tsc` commences. Clearly neither `tsc` nor `scripts` waited for the compilation step to complete.

When these tasks return their streams, the output looks rather different:

```
$ gulp scripts
[21:42:25] Using gulpfile ~/my-project/gulpfile.js
[21:42:25] Starting 'tsc'...
[21:42:25] Compiling TypeScript files using tsc version 1.0.1.0
[21:42:32] Finished 'tsc' after 6.65 s
[21:42:32] Starting 'scripts'...
[21:42:32] Finished 'scripts' after 204 ms
```

Here the sequence makes sense, and the reported durations meet expectations.

Comment: What if you have a gulp task that is async but does not involve streams? Can you call a `done()` function or return a promise?

Comment: You can define the task so that it accepts a callback function as the final parameter, or you can return a promise. See here: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/v3.9.1/docs/API.md#gulptaskname--deps-fn