# gulp intermittedly creating destination directories

Tags: javascript, gulp

## Why does gulp only sometimes create the subdirectory, even when there are no changes to the source files/directories and I am just rerunning gulp?

Sometimes my gulpfile works just fine.. like after running it the first time after creating the build directory:

```
PS C:\Users\RobertoTomás\OneDrive\Público\projects\Overwatch> gulp
[09:56:11] Requiring external module babel-register
[09:56:13] Using gulpfile ~\OneDrive\Público\projects\Overwatch\gulpfile.babel.js
[09:56:13] Starting 'default'...
[09:56:13] Starting 'clean'...
[09:56:13] Starting 'root'...
[09:56:13] Finished 'root' after 6.23 ms
[09:56:13] Starting 'templates'...
[09:56:13] Finished 'templates' after 1.68 ms
[09:56:13] Starting 'css'...
[09:56:13] Finished 'css' after 7.43 ms
[09:56:13] Starting 'sass'...
[09:56:13] Finished 'sass' after 6.96 ms
[09:56:13] Starting 'scripts'...
[09:56:13] Finished 'scripts' after 3.88 ms
[09:56:13] Finished 'default' after 39 ms
[09:56:13] Finished 'clean' after 91 ms
[09:56:14] File dev\styles\bootstrap-theme.css found.
[09:56:14] Processed media queries:
[09:56:14]   @media (max-width: 767px)
[09:56:14] File dev\styles\bootstrap-theme.css created.
[09:56:14] File dev\styles\bootstrap-theme.min.css found.
[09:56:14] Processed media queries:
[09:56:14]   @media (max-width:767px)
[09:56:14] File dev\styles\bootstrap-theme.min.css created.
[09:56:15] File dev\styles\bootstrap.css found.
[09:56:15] Processed media queries:
[09:56:15]   @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0)
[09:56:15]   @media (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation: landscape)
[09:56:15]   @media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d)
[09:56:15]   @media (min-width: 768px)
[09:56:15]   @media screen and (min-width: 768px)
[09:56:15]   @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px)
[09:56:15]   @media (min-width: 992px)
[09:56:15]   @media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px)
[09:56:15]   @media (min-width: 1200px)
[09:56:15]   @media screen and (max-width: 767px)
[09:56:15]   @media (max-width: 767px)
[09:56:15]   @media print
[09:56:15] File dev\styles\bootstrap.css created.
[09:56:15] File dev\styles\bootstrap.min.css found.
[09:56:15] Processed media queries:
[09:56:15]   @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)
[09:56:15]   @media (max-device-width:480px) and (orientation:landscape)
[09:56:15]   @media all and (transform-3d),(-webkit-transform-3d)
[09:56:15]   @media (min-width:768px)
[09:56:15]   @media screen and (min-width:768px)
[09:56:15]   @media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px)
[09:56:15]   @media (min-width:992px)
[09:56:15]   @media (min-width:992px) and (max-width:1199px)
[09:56:15]   @media (min-width:1200px)
[09:56:15]   @media screen and (max-width:767px)
[09:56:15]   @media (max-width:767px)
[09:56:15]   @media print
[09:56:15] File dev\styles\bootstrap.min.css created.
[09:56:16] File dev\styles\main.css found.
[09:56:16] File dev\styles\main.css created.
[BS] Access URLs:
 ------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://192.168.1.9:3000
 ------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://192.168.1.9:3001
 ------------------------------------
[BS] Serving files from: ./build/
[BS] 5 files changed (bootstrap-theme.min.css, bootstrap-theme.min.min.css, bootstrap.min.css, bootstrap.min.min.css, ma
in.min.css)
[BS] 7 files changed (404.html, index.html, browserconfig.xml, apple-touch-icon.png, tile-wide.png, tile.png, favicon.ic
o)
[BS] 5 files changed (bootstrap.min.js, bootstrap.min.min.js, jquery-3.1.0.min.js, main.min.js, modernizr-2.8.3-respond-
1.4.2.min.min.js)
```

But most of the time (but *not* always), I gett an error with the `styles` subdirectory:

```
PS C:\Users\RobertoTomás\OneDrive\Público\projects\Overwatch> gulp
[09:57:31] Requiring external module babel-register
[09:57:33] Using gulpfile ~\OneDrive\Público\projects\Overwatch\gulpfile.babel.js
[09:57:33] Starting 'default'...
[09:57:33] Starting 'clean'...
[09:57:33] Starting 'root'...
[09:57:33] Finished 'root' after 6.26 ms
[09:57:33] Starting 'templates'...
[09:57:33] Finished 'templates' after 1.77 ms
[09:57:33] Starting 'css'...
[09:57:33] Finished 'css' after 7.78 ms
[09:57:33] Starting 'sass'...
[09:57:33] Finished 'sass' after 6.5 ms
[09:57:33] Starting 'scripts'...
[09:57:33] Finished 'scripts' after 3.82 ms
[09:57:33] Finished 'default' after 39 ms
[09:57:34] File dev\styles\bootstrap-theme.css found.
[09:57:34] Processed media queries:
[09:57:34]   @media (max-width: 767px)
[09:57:34] File dev\styles\bootstrap-theme.css created.
[09:57:34] File dev\styles\bootstrap-theme.min.css found.
[09:57:34] Processed media queries:
[09:57:34]   @media (max-width:767px)
[09:57:34] File dev\styles\bootstrap-theme.min.css created.
[09:57:35] File dev\styles\bootstrap.css found.
[09:57:35] Processed media queries:
[09:57:35]   @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0)
[09:57:35]   @media (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation: landscape)
[09:57:35]   @media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d)
[09:57:35]   @media (min-width: 768px)
[09:57:35]   @media screen and (min-width: 768px)
[09:57:35]   @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px)
[09:57:35]   @media (min-width: 992px)
[09:57:35]   @media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px)
[09:57:35]   @media (min-width: 1200px)
[09:57:35]   @media screen and (max-width: 767px)
[09:57:35]   @media (max-width: 767px)
[09:57:35]   @media print
[09:57:35] File dev\styles\bootstrap.css created.
[09:57:36] File dev\styles\bootstrap.min.css found.
[09:57:36] Processed media queries:
[09:57:36]   @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)
[09:57:36]   @media (max-device-width:480px) and (orientation:landscape)
[09:57:36]   @media all and (transform-3d),(-webkit-transform-3d)
[09:57:36]   @media (min-width:768px)
[09:57:36]   @media screen and (min-width:768px)
[09:57:36]   @media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px)
[09:57:36]   @media (min-width:992px)
[09:57:36]   @media (min-width:992px) and (max-width:1199px)
[09:57:36]   @media (min-width:1200px)
[09:57:36]   @media screen and (max-width:767px)
[09:57:36]   @media (max-width:767px)
[09:57:36]   @media print
[09:57:36] File dev\styles\bootstrap.min.css created.
[09:57:36] File dev\styles\main.css found.
[09:57:36] File dev\styles\main.css created.
[09:57:36] Plumber found unhandled error:
 Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 'C:\Users\RobertoTomás\OneDrive\Público\projects\Overwatch\build\styles
\bootstrap-theme.min.css'
[09:57:36] Plumber found unhandled error:
 Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 'C:\Users\RobertoTomás\OneDrive\Público\projects\Overwatch\build\styles
\bootstrap-theme.min.css'
[09:57:36] Finished 'clean' after 2.94 s
[BS] Access URLs:
 ------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://192.168.1.9:3000
 ------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://192.168.1.9:3001
 ------------------------------------
[BS] Serving files from: ./build/
[BS] 7 files changed (404.html, index.html, browserconfig.xml, apple-touch-icon.png, tile-wide.png, tile.png, favicon.ic
o)
[BS] 5 files changed (bootstrap.min.js, bootstrap.min.min.js, jquery-3.1.0.min.js, main.min.js, modernizr-2.8.3-respond-
1.4.2.min.min.js)
```

The whole `styles` subdirectory doesn't get created in `build`.

Here's my gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var autoPrefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
//if node version is lower than v.0.1.2
//require('es6-promise').polyfill();
var cssComb = require('gulp-csscomb');
var cmq = require('gulp-merge-media-queries');
var cleanCss = require('gulp-clean-css');
var browserify = require('gulp-browserify');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var reload = browserSync.reload

var clean = require('gulp-clean');

gulp.task('clean', function (done) {
    gulp.src('build/*', { read: false })
        .pipe(clean())
    done()
})

gulp.task('sass', function (done) {
    gulp.src(['dev/styles/**/*.scss', 'dev/styles/**/*.sass'])
        .pipe(plumber({
            handleError: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
                this.emit('end');
            }
        }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(autoPrefixer())
        .pipe(cssComb())
        .pipe(cmq({ log: true }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/styles'))
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: '.min'
        }))
        .pipe(cleanCss())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/styles'))
        .pipe(reload({ stream: true }))
    done()
});
gulp.task('css', function (done) {
    gulp.src(['dev/styles/**/*.css'])
        .pipe(plumber({
            handleError: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
                this.emit('end');
            }
        }))
        .pipe(autoPrefixer())
        .pipe(cssComb())
        .pipe(cmq({ log: true }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/styles'))
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: '.min'
        }))
        .pipe(cleanCss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/styles'))
        .pipe(reload({ stream: true }))
    done()
});
gulp.task('scripts', function (done) {
    gulp.src(['dev/scripts/**/*.js'])
        .pipe(plumber({
            handleError: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
                this.emit('end');
            }
        }))
        .pipe(browserify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/scripts'))
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: '.min'
        }))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/scripts'))
        .pipe(reload({ stream: true }))
    done()
});
gulp.task('templates', function (done) {
    gulp.src(['dev/hypermedia/**/*.html'])
        .pipe(plumber({
            handleError: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
                this.emit('end');
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/hypermedia/'))
        .pipe(reload({ stream: true }))
    done()
});
gulp.task('root', function (done) {
    gulp.src(['dev/**/*.html', 'dev/**/*.xml', 'dev/**/*.png', 'dev/**/*.ico'])
        .pipe(plumber({
            handleError: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
                this.emit('end');
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'))
        .pipe(reload({ stream: true }))
    done()
});

gulp.task('all', function (done) {
    gulp.start('root', 'templates', 'css', 'sass', 'scripts')
    done()
})

gulp.task('default', ['clean', 'root', 'templates', 'css', 'sass', 'scripts'], function (done) {
    gulp.watch('dev/scripts/**/*.js', ['scripts']);
    gulp.watch('dev/styles/**/*.css', ['css']);
    gulp.watch(['dev/styles/**/*.scss', 'dev/styles/**/*.sass'], ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('hypermedia/**/*.html', ['templates']);
    gulp.watch(['dev/**/*.html', 'dev/**/*.xml', 'dev/**/*.png', 'dev/**/*.ico'], ['root']);
    browserSync.init({ server: './build/' });
    done()
});
```

This is particurally weird because, I only delete the style directory at the beginning (the dependancy, actually) of the `default` task..and I immediately recreate it (still in dependency. It should still be there.

I also tried implementing this with a promise, or as a series of `.on('end'` calls, with and without the `done()` callbacks, but I didn't find a solution in those either.

#### bonus question:

how can I match `.min.js` separately from `.js` so I am not processing 3rdparty js files? I'd be happy to use a `vendor` subdirectory, but then Im not sure how to include all subdirectories for processing *except* vendor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. You're not returning your streams**.

You need to do this in every task:

```
gulp.task('sass',function(){
   return gulp.src(['dev/styles/**/*.scss','dev/styles/**/*.sass'])
```

You also need to remove all the pointless `done()` callbacks you have strewn around in your code.

Further reading: [Async task support](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#async-task-support), [Does a gulp task have to return anything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079118/does-a-gulp-task-have-to-return-anything)

**2. You're running all your tasks in parallel.**

```
gulp.task('default', ['clean', 'root', 'templates', 'css', 'sass', 'scripts'], function (done) {
```

The above doesn't run `clean`, `root`, `templates`, `css`, `sass` and `scripts` in order. It runs them all at the same time. That's why you get that `ENOENT` error. You're deleting files in your `clean` task while the other tasks are creating them.

The best approach in your case would probably be to use [`run-sequence`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence):

```
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('dev/scripts/**/*.js', ['scripts']);
  gulp.watch('dev/styles/**/*.css', ['css']);
  gulp.watch(['dev/styles/**/*.scss', 'dev/styles/**/*.sass'], ['sass']);
  gulp.watch('hypermedia/**/*.html', ['templates']);
  gulp.watch(['dev/**/*.html', 'dev/**/*.xml', 'dev/**/*.png', 'dev/**/*.ico'], ['root']);
});

gulp.task('serve', function() {
  browserSync.init({ server: './build/' });
});

gulp.task('default', function(done) {
  runSequence('clean', ['root', 'templates', 'css', 'sass', 'scripts'], 'watch', 'serve', done);
});
```

The above ensures the following task order:

1. `clean`
2. `root`, `templates`, `css`, `sass`, `scripts` in parallel
3. `watch`
4. `serve`

Further reading: [How to run Gulp tasks sequentially one after the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824546/how-to-run-gulp-tasks-sequentially-one-after-the-other?rq=1)

Comment: thank you! I'm still a little unseure about when the callback is required vs not .. you use it yourself in the defult task for some reason — in any case, implementing your suggestions resolved my problem precisely. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For the bonus question: you can exclude a file or pattern by giving it the `!` prefix. If your js files (both minified and not) were in the top level of `src`, you'd use `['src/*.js','!src/*.min.js']`.

See also the [Glob Primer](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#glob-primer).

Comment: wow thank you Henry, didnt expect anyone to come back for that :)